# Occasional nil return from NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have what I considered until now stable code that exports date into a file that can later be imported. I discovered a weird case that I hard coded here:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *sd = @"03/26/17 02:30:35";
NSString *ed = @"03/26/17 05:10:17";

NSLog(@"sd = %@", [df dateFromString:sd]);
NSLog(@"ed = %@", [df dateFromString:ed]);
```

which gives:

```
sd = (null)
ed = Sun Mar 26 05:10:17 2017
```

Does anyone have a hint?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

In many countries of the northern hemisphere on March 26, 2017 the daylight saving time begins where the time from 2:00 to 2:59 is skipped.

Comment: Yes. The OP is in France and that is indeed when daylight savings happened in France this year.